# C union member gives particular/wrong value when other member is set to a new value. Why is this output in following code in C?

Tags: c, unions

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  union Data
  {
    char str[20];    
    int i;
    float f;
  }data;

  data.i=20;
  data.f=220.5;
  printf("%d\n",(data.i));

  return 0;
}
```

The output is:1130135552.  I used gcc complier on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Can someone explain the output?

The members `data.i` and `data.f` occupy same memory location, so output should be 220. But why output is 1130135552?

Comment: Can you explain why you expected `220` ?

Comment: Why are you using a `union`?

Comment: data.i and data.f  occupy same memory location. Here, we initialised data.f=220.5. This value will be stored in the same memory location of data.i. Hence, the output should be integral part of 220.5 , that is , 220.

Comment: `data.f` is a `float`. Why should the assignment result in a conversion of floating point value to integer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you are already aware that `union` shares memory location between the members inside. In case of `union` compiler allocated the memory equal to the max size of the member and use the same memory for all the members.

Hence when you execute `data.f=220.5;`, shared memory location between `i` and `f` holding `data.i=20;` got overwritten to a new value (220.5) with binary representation as follows :

[image]

Now again, when this value is read as a signed integer `int` it will be interpreted without conversion as `1130135552` in decimal representation. Hence you are getting `1130135552`.

Further if you want to use all members of union, then struct is the answer.

```
struct Data
{
    char str[20];
    int i;
    float f;
} data;

data.i=20;
data.f=220.5;
printf("%d\n",data.i);
```

For more information on `union` and `struct` Please refer the following from [Difference between Structure and Union](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-structure-union-c/):
[image]

Answer (score 6):

According to C11 Section 6.5.2.3 Footnote 95

> If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the
>   same as the member last used to store a value in the object, **the
>   appropriate part of the object representation of the value is
>   reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type** as described
>   in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type punning’’). This might be
>   a trap representation.

The specific output depends on the layout of the members in memory and the type. Therefore, when you store `data.f` and then access `data.i`, the bit patterns in the memory of `data.f` is reinterpreted as an integer.

Note the following:

```
int a = 1;
float b = 1;
```

These two although may seem to have a similar layout on memory, but they are stored differently. In the case of integer, it will be generally stored in a two's complement format (although it can be other formats as well), and a floating point will be generally stored using the [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) format (although it can be different). Therefore, trying to interpret a number stored using IEEE754 as integer will get you something totally different.

Also, not that, according to C11 Section 6.2.6.1 Paragraph 7

> When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the
>   bytes of the object representation that do not correspond to that
>   member but do correspond to other members take unspecified values.

Therefore, if you assign to a member of an object of a union, then the values in the bytes of other location which is not used by the member which you assigned will have unspecified values.

Comment: @user694733: I did not understand your point. Can you elaborate? Also, have a look at my update.

Comment: I am saying that 6.2.6.1 is not relevant and can be removed. It specifies what happens to bytes from `data.str[4]` to `data.str[19]`. You addition from  6.5.2.3  is correct though.

Comment: You are right, 6.5.2.3 is not directly relevant, but definitely important. But 6.5.2.3 is precise. I will restructure and answer.

Comment: 6.2.6.1/7 would be relevant only if `sizeof(int) > sizeof(float)`

Comment: As a nit-pick, the only relevant part to cite is (C17 6.5.2.3 §3) "The value is that of the named member". The non-normative footnote only clarifies that no conversion takes place, the value is simply reinterpreted according to the relevant type representation in 6.2. But also that the code is well-defined behavior in C (apart from potential trap representations), unlike C++.

Comment: @Lundin: Agreed, but I believe the footnote clarifies it in a much better way and therefore possibly can be better read an an answer. But, why the code's behaviour will be well defined? I believe it should be implementation defined, isn't it?

Comment: It entirely depends on which types there are.

Comment: There are a few platforms where writing a half-word may take longer than writing a full word.  The cited provision exists to allow compilers targeting such platforms to process a request to write a half-word member in a larger union by writing a whole word.  I don't think it was intended to pass any judgment about whether compilers that behave in such fashion should be viewed as being better or worse than those which generate extra code to avoid disturbing storage beyond the end of the sub-object being written.

Answer (score 2):

If I may, let's restrict this answer to the case where `sizeof(float)` is the same as `sizeof(int)`, that `float` is a single precision IEEE754 type, and `int` is a 2's complement type. If you don't understand what I'm saying here, ignore this paragraph for now: it's here in an attempt to make this answer watertight; a bit like the legalese in a financial contract.

A `float` is a remarkable type capable of representing numbers in a large range with a remarkable amount of precision. The *format* it uses internally to achieve this is a a complex one. If you want to know more, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754.

When you write `data.f = 220.5;`, you are setting the first `sizeof(float)` bytes in your `union` to have the memory associated with the constant `220.5f`.

But an `int` uses an entirely different format. When you output the `int` member of the union, you recover the `int` with value `1130135552`. This is related to the `220.5f` in that both have exactly the same pattern of bits.

The `char str[20];` in your `union` is a red herring.

Answer (score 2):

As explicited by [phoxis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51817648/6337519), the standard declares that the value is unspecified.

However, pragmatically, this is a good example of binary interpretation.

I assume the width for an `int` and `float` on your platform is 32 bits, and a floating-point value follows the [IEEE 754 representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

What happens here:

```
data.f=220.5;
```

This statement writes the floating-point value as binary `0100 0011 0101 1100 1000 0000 0000 0000` in the memory location of `data`, overwriting any previous value.

The next time the value is accessed is when read as an integer: `data.i` member access in your `printf` call. The value read, in binary, is still `0100 0011 0101 1100 1000 0000 0000 0000`, and **as a signed integer, this is interpreted without conversion as `1130135552`**.

If you want the value to be converted, you have to read the value as a floating-point (using `data.f`) and convert it to an integer value with a cast:

```
printf("%d\n",(int)(data.f));
```

Answer (score 1):

`data.i` and `data.f` share the same memory, but the interpretation of a value is different in integer and float.

With a float converter you get following values:

```
220.5 in float means: 
sign: 1
exponent: 134 
mantissa: 1.72265625 encoded as :6062080

binary representation:0 10000110 10111001000000000000000  (sign, exponent, mant.)
hex representation: 0x435c8000
dezimal representation:1130135552  (the value you get!!)
```