# Manipulation of union variable in C

Tags: c, unions

Here is a union containing two types of variable `int` and `char`. If I am assign some value to `int` variable then what will be present in `char` variable?

for e.g.

```
union a {
  int x;
  char j;
  char k;
} ua;
int main(){
  ua.x = 0xabcd;
  printf("%x",ua.j);
}
```

Here what value will be printed and how?

Comment: For the *what* why don't you just compile and run it?

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do? This looks like a typical [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @sp2danny - Sure it does. `char` has not alignment problems, or trap representations. And C explicitly allows the punning.

Comment: @StoryTeller but it depends on the endianness

Comment: @Jabberwocky to me it seems more like abstract curiosity, in that I'm not sure they're trying to solve an actual problem, just trying to understand how things work. Which, sure, would be better answered by reading a good guide on the subject...

Comment: @Jabberwocky - Sure, but that's implementation defined. To say it's not well-defined is to stipulate there's something inherently wrong with it.

Comment: @StoryTeller OK got your point

Comment: @sp2danny - There is one thing it must do. Reinterpret and read the first byte of `x`, whatever that may hold. And if you wish to argue semantics, then please be precise in your language.

Comment: You can get answer of What? - just by compiling and executing it.
For Why? please have a look here -https://stackoverflow.com/a/51817644/8238512

Comment: Note that the union members `j` and `k` refer to the same storage and are just different names for the same byte.

Comment: by compiling and running the code I will get answer the answer but the question is how it is coming? @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: This is too broad to be answered. Answers depend on endianess, compiler implementation of char, CPU used etc etc. A better question would be to show your results and mention which compiler + version, CPU and system you ran the code on.

Answer (score 3):

As per the C11 standard:

> **6.2.6 Representations of types**
>   **6.2.6.1 General**
>   ...
>   5 Certain object representations need not represent a value of the object type. **If the stored value of an object has such a representation and is read by an lvalue expression that does
>   not have character type, the behavior is undefined**. If such a representation is produced
>   by a side effect that modifies all or any part of the object by an lvalue expression that
>   does not have character type, the behavior is undefined.50) Such a representation is called
>   a trap representation.

But the lvalue expression here has `char` type, so this is well-defined behavior.

Also of relevance is this note from

> **6.5.2.3 Structure and union members:**
>   ...
>   95) If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to
>   store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted
>   as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type
>   punning’’). This might be a trap representation

What the `printf` statement will actually print will depend on the endianess of the system, which is to say it is implementation defined.

Comment: assume it is a big endian

Comment: big-endian means the big end is stored first. So *ab will be printed.

Answer (score 2):

This code may help you to understand what is happening:

```
union a {
    int x;
    char j;
    char k;
}ua;

int main(){
    ua.x = 0xabcd;
    printf("%x\n",ua.x);    // Print x as hexadecimal:    abcd
    printf("%x\n",ua.j);    // Print j as hexadecimal:    ffffffcd
    printf("%x\n",ua.k);    // Print k as hexadecimal:    ffffffcd
    printf("%d\n",ua.x);    // Print x as decimal:        43981
    printf("%c\n",ua.j);    // Print j as char:           �
    printf("%c\n",ua.k);    // Print k as char:           �
}
```

When writting 0xabcd into an int, the memory space for the int is filled with this hexadecimal number (abcd) which value in decimal is 43981. You can print both values with %x and %d respectively.

As @Jonathan Leffler said, j and k are just different names that refer to the same byte of the union. This is why the %x prints a value finished in "cd" (the last byte of the value written, due to your system seems to use big endianness) in both cases. The "char value" is represented as � .

If you want to know why there is printed ffffff before the value, check: [Printing hexadecimal characters in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060170/printing-hexadecimal-characters-in-c).

Comment: Thanks @Ganathor. now I got it.